# IE Cache Settings

Tags: internet-explorer

What does the following IE cache setting do: "every time i visit the webpage"

Does it cause the browser to ignore the Expiration and other Cache related http headers? Is it at the webpage (address URL level) or is it for every object loaded by the browser (say an image url referenced in the html of the page)?

Answer (score 0):

it basically saves ur cache until the lifetime of the ie instance

Comment: sorry meant to ask abt this option "every time i visit the webpage"

Answer (score 0):

This article explains the settings: http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf

The short answer is that those radiobutton settings control only what happens when the server doesn't specify a cache policy using the headers.